# Navigator Geolocation get CurrentPosition not working suddenly

Tags: html, navigator

Is it possible that the API is down?

I tried: 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(foo){console.log(foo)})
on my browser it returns undefined , any solutions for this?

Comment: Maybe you didn't give your browser permission, or denied permission by accident. A window like this should pop up https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0wpn.jpg - to protect your user's privacy it'll only geolocate them if they click allow

Comment: I granted permission. Yeah A window like that popped up asking for my permission and i Clicked allow.